# Python — confused by numpy's piecewise function

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, piecewise

I'm trying to implement a piecewise function in Python. Since I'm using quite a few tools from numpy, I simply import everything from it (i.e. `from numpy import *`). My piecewise function is defined as

```
LinQuad = piecewise( t, [t < 1, t >= 1], [lambda t : t, lambda t : t**2] )
```

which results in the error `NameError: global name 't' is not defined`. I don't understand why I should define `t` — after all, it is not necessary to define `t` for a simple lambda function `Lin = lambda t : t`. In some examples the domain of `t` is defined, but I don't know at which values the function `LinQuad` will be evaluated. What to do?

Comment: _"it is not necessary to define t for a simple lambda function `Lin = lambda t : t`"_ - that's because `lambda t:` is a python language construct that defines `t` within the scope of the expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no numpy expert, but it looks to me like you're expecting piecewise to return a function that you can then use elsewhere.  That's not what it does - it calculates the function result itself.  You could probably write a lambda expression that would take an arbitrary domain and return your calculation on it:

```
LinQuad = lambda x: piecewise(x, [x < 1, x >= 1], [lambda t: t, lambda t: t**2])
```

I am none too sure about defining the condlist boolean arrays there - presumably that's something specific to numpy.

Or if appropriate to your situation:

```
def LinQuad(x):
   return piecewise(x, [x < 1, x >= 1], [lambda t: t, lambda t: t**2])
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.piecewise` requires that you define the input domain at the time you call it:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html

You can't really get around how the method is specified. While you can use lambda functions with it, `np.piecewise` does not generate a method that can then be applied against arbitrary domains.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be enough to know that `LinQuad` will be evaluated at some values between `0` and `4`? Or do I have to know the exact values at which `LinQuad` will be evaluated? In other words, how exactly do I define the input domain?