# piecewise linear function with numpy.piecewise

Tags: python, numpy, piecewise

I am trying to use the data from two `x0` and `y0` coordinate arrays to create a function that uses the provided `x0` and `y0` to compute a piecewise series of segments.

For doing that, I create a function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

def broken_line(x, x0, y0):
    cl = []
    fl = []
    for i in range(len(x0)-1):
        ab = np.polyfit(x0[i:i+2], y0[i:i+2], 1)
        # Compute and append a "condition" interval
        cl.append(np.logical_and(x >= x0[i], x <= x0[i+1]))
        # Create a line function for the interval
        fl.append(lambda x: x*ab[0] + ab[1])
    return(np.piecewise(x, condlist=cl, funclist=fl))
```

and then to test it I plot the results of

```py
x0 = np.array([1, 3, 5, 10])
y0 = np.array([2, 1, 5, 7])

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 30)

pl.plot(x, broken_line(x, x0, y0))
pl.plot(x0, y0)
pl.show()
```

[image]

However, the results is not as I would expect.
I had a look at other posts on the topic, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574966/python-confused-by-numpys-piecewise-function) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358953/matplotlib-plot-piecewise-linear-function-with-three-parts), together with the [numpy.piecewise](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) documentation.
However, I was not able to figure out why the code is not working as expected. It looks like only the last definition of `lambda` is considered.
Suggestions are all welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ab` in the lambda definition is defined in the surrounding scope, thus changes with every iteration. Only the `ab` values of the last iteration are reflected into all the lambda funtions.

One possible solution is to use a factory method for the creation of the lambda function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

def lambda_factory(ab):
    return lambda x:x*ab[0]+ab[1]

def broken_line(x, x0, y0):
    cl = []
    fl = []
    for i in range(len(x0)-1):
        ab = np.polyfit(x0[i:i+2], y0[i:i+2], 1)
        # Compute and append a "condition" interval
        cl.append(np.logical_and(x >= x0[i], x <= x0[i+1]))
        # Create a line function for the interval
        fl.append(lambda_factory(ab))
    return(np.piecewise(x, condlist=cl, funclist=fl))

x0 = np.array([1, 3, 5, 10])
y0 = np.array([2, 1, 5, 7])

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 30)

pl.plot(x, broken_line(x, x0, y0))
pl.plot(x0, y0)
pl.show()
```

Another solution is to save `ab` in a variable local to the lambda, thus using

```
fl.append(lambda x, ab=ab:x*ab[0]+ab[1])
```

within the loop. Here you create a local variable `ab` of the outer scope variable `ab`.

In both cases the result looks like this:

[image: Resulting piecewise fit]

For further reference see the [python faq](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem (I implemented the 2nd solution, maybe more "compact")! Thank you also for the link to the python faq